# Horizontal collectionView freezes when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, kingfisher

I have a collectionView and tableview in a same viewcontroller with separate views. Im using Kingfisher for downloading images. I can scroll tableview without any problems. But when I scroll collectionview the app freezes, and after some time app is crashing and getting debug message as "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue".

[image: This is the screen shot]

```
func setupCollectionView(){
    let cell = UINib(nibName: "FilterCollectionCell", bundle: Bundle(for: FilterCollectionCell.self))
    self.collectionView.register(cell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FilterCollectionCell")
    self.collectionFlowOut.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sharedData.offerDetails.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilterCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCollectionCell

    if self.sharedData.offerDetails.count > indexPath.row{
        let offerDetail = self.sharedData.offerDetails[indexPath.row]
        cell.price.text = offerDetail.currency + " " + offerDetail.lowestFare.withCommas()

        if let firstSector = offerDetail.flightDetails.first,
            let firstOption = firstSector.options.first,
            let firstSegment = firstOption.flightSegments.first{
            cell.flightName.text = firstSegment.airlineName
            let imgURL = self.sharedData.imageURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "{airlineID}", with: firstSegment.airlineCode)
            let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "AirlineIcon")
            let url = URL(string: imgURL)
            cell.logoImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            cell.logoImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: placeholderImage, options: [], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    return cell
}
```

This is my collectionView methods

When I removed estimatedItemSize, scrolling works perfectly, but I cant fit the cell size based on the label content.

```
        self.collectionFlowOut.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

Comment: Use instruments to find the memory problems while loading collectionview.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/

Comment: But I coudnt find any issue in codes that utilize so much of memory

Comment: Can you post code of `collectionFlowOut `, cause I think that problem is there?

Comment: @MMiroslav collectionFlowOut is my outlet that I created from storyboard, and I dont have any codes for this.

Comment: Did you try `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` instead of `estimatedItemSize`?

Comment: @MMiroslav I tried it, if i apply this delegate method, view controller is not appearing. Its entering in an infinity loop something like that

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.setNeedsLayout()
```

why you call them in such way

Comment: Removed, still same issue

Comment: When I removed estimatedItemSize, scrolling works perfectly, but I cant fit the cell size based on the label content.